# Garry's Mod gamemode scripting (lua) - How do I tell if an object is inside a hollow cylinder?

Tags: collision-detection, vector, lua, modding

I'm fiddling about with gMod trying to make a gamemode where you have to throw a piece of cake into a cylinder that spawns on the map.

This is the code I'm using to spawn the cylinder:

```
local ent = ents.Create( "prop_physics" )
ent:SetModel("models/props_phx/construct/windows/window_curve360x1.mdl")
ent:SetPos( Vector(math.random(100,2500), math.random(1500,-1000), 150) )
--ent:SetPos( math.random(-1500,-2500), math.random(-1500,-2500), 100 )
ent:Spawn()

cleanup.Add( self.Owner, "props", ent )

undo.Create( "Spawned_Cylinder" )
undo.AddEntity( ent )
undo.SetPlayer ( self.Owner )
undo.Finish()
```

The cake throwing part is basically just a SWEP that shoots the 'cakehat' prop. How would I test whether there is a piece of a cake inside the cylinder?

Answer (score 1):

You take the center of the cake and determine if it's within distance of the radius and also within the distance of the height. It's been a while since I've done gmod lua so bear with me.

```
local cylinderCenterPos = Vector(0,0,0)
local cylinderHeight = 2
local cylinderRadius = 2
local cakePos = cake.GetPos()

local radiusDist = math.sqrt(math.pow(cylinderCenterPos.x - cakePos.x,2) + math.pow(cylinderCenterPos.y - cakePos.y,2)) --Horizontal axes
local heightDist = math.abs(cylinderCenterPos.z - cakePos.z) --Up axis

if radiusDist <= cylinderRadius and heightDist <= heightDist then
    --The cake is in the cylinder
end
```

Note that this will test if the center of the cake is within the cylinder and assumes a cylinder that's height is running along the up vector.

Checking on a rotated cylinder is a bit harder as you have to check using the transformed axis of the cylinder (however it's rotated).

Comment: I've never done gmod Lua, but I'd assume it has support for collision-detection already?  It would be absurd for every mod to reimplement collision-detection on its own, in Lua, instead of using the Source engine's built-in capabilities...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft The only collision detection that Gmod exposes too my knowledge is [StartTouch and friends](http://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/ENTITY/StartTouch) b/c it only partially exposes the full Source engine capabilities. This exact thing is what brush triggers do but I don't think you can place those in Gmod (after the map is compiled in Hammer) and they also must be static. He/she is trying to make a prop_physics and also spawn it at runtime. Reimplementing it (it's only like 5 lines of code) is probably the fastest and only possible option.